# Error when using busboy inside of firebase function to send file to google cloud bucket

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

After initiating my firebase app on the server side in order to handle all the authentication and setting up my firebase functions I learned I can't pass my firebase instance to the front end in order for me to use firebase storage there so I am now trying to pass my file array to my express server.

Originally I was using multer but it seems like firebase and multer don't get along very well so I'm just looking for what might be a good package to use as a substitute for multer any suggestions are welcome. I'll post how I'm passing all my data below so you have a better understanding of my structure.

Even if I can't upload to firebase storage from the backend that isn't an issue because I can easily use a google cloud bucket but the issue with multer still remains. So any suggested libraries?

Client-side upload (Just a basic react-dropzone)

```
  const {acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone();

  const files = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path}
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <Fragment>

      <section class={uploadStyle.uploadBox}>
        <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone'})}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          <p>Click or drop files here</p> 
        </div>
        <aside>
          <h4>Files</h4>
          <ul>{files}</ul>
        </aside>
      </section>

      
      <div class='text-center mt-5'>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
          Upload New Files
        </button>
        {GatherFileName(acceptedFiles)}
      </div>
      <div class='text-center mt-5'>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>{fileUpload(acceptedFiles)}}>Submit</button>
      </div>

    </Fragment>
    
  );
```

fetch request passing data to the server

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', accepetedfiles);

try{

  const response = await fetch(`http://someUrl`,{
    method:"POST",
    body: formData
  })

  const jsonData = await response.json()

  console.log(jsonData)

}catch(error){

    console.log(error)

}
```

Server-side fire handling (Where I'm stuck. Wont work because I cannot access my formdata)

```
try{

    const formData = req.body;
    for(let file = 0;file < files.length;file++){

        let storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${files[file].path}`);
        let uploadTask = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, files[file]);

    }

    res.json('no error:\n\nfiles: ' + 
        JSON.stringify(files) + '\n\nfile: ' + JSON.stringify(files[0]) + 
        '\n\nfiles len: ' + files.length)

}catch(error){
    res.json('error: ' + error + '\n\nfiles: ' + req.body + '\n\nfiles raw: ' + req.body.files)
    res.json('Error: ' + error)
}
```

Update:

Instead of uploading to firebase storage, I'm just going to try and upload to a google cloud bucket as I was doing previously. I switched my code over to using busboy which I tested in a local envirment and it worked without any issues. However if I do not add a header like is suggested on SO I receive `Error: Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final` which seems to have multiple ways to resolve it.

I've gone ahead and made sure all my packages we're updated and current but still get the same error. So I tried adding a header and am getting the same issue but after adding a few console.logs it seems the line that is causing my crash is where I am detecting a file.

Updated code:

Client-side (same as before)

fetch request passing data to the server

```
export default async function UploadToStorage(acceptedFiles,fileVals){//Index are 1-1

  console.log(acceptedFiles)
  
  try{
      for(let fileCount = 0;fileCount < acceptedFiles.length;fileCount++){
          let boundary = Math.random().toString().substr(8) + "--";

          const formData = new FormData();

          let file = acceptedFiles[fileCount]
  
          let blob = file.slice(0,file.size)
          let newFile = new File([blob], file.name, {type: "text/plain"});
  
          formData.append(file.name,newFile)
          
          const response = await fetch(`https://someUrl`,{
              method:"POST",
              headers: {"Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data;boundary='+boundary},
              body:formData
          })
      
          const jsonData = await response.json()
          console.log('jsonData: ' + jsonData)

          if(!jsonData){
            return false
          }else{
            return true
          }
    
      }
  }catch(error){

      console.log(error)

  }

}
```

Server-side fire handling (Where I'm stuck. Crash is at line `busboy.on('file' ...`)

```
app.post('/uploadNewFiles',async(req,res)=>{

    console.log('made it to uploadNewFiles')
    
    try{

        let buffers = []
        const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        console.log('busboy created')
        busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
            console.log('busboy detected file')
            file.on('data',(data)=>{
                buffers.push(data)
            })

            console.log(buffers)

            file.on('end',()=>{
                buffers = Buffer.concat(buffers)
                console.log(buffers.toString())
            })

            const newFile = bucket.file(filename.filename)

            newFile.save(buffers.toString(),(error=>{
                if(!error){
                    console.log('Upload complete')
                }else{
                    console.log('Upload issue')
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }))

        });
        busboy.on('finish', function() {
            res.json("That's all");
        });
        return req.pipe(busboy);


    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.json(false)
    }

})
```